# Рамка у полосы прокрутки

Tags: css, прокрутка

Добрый день,
есть модальное окно, в нем блок с прокруткой
в Мозилле при прокрутке у бегунка появляется черная рамка, которая пропадает через некоторое время (пара секунд)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему она появляется и можно ли с этим как-то бороться?)
В других браузерах все норм

Answer (score 0):

Решено
Дело было в том, что для позиционирования по центру экрана к модальному окну применялось свойство transform: translate
Из-за этого видимо криво сдвигалось все и рамка полосы прокрутки не совпадала с самой полосой визуально
Решение - сдвиг окна с помощью отрицательных маргинов

Криво было из-за того, что размеры окна - нечетное количество пикселей, при сдвиге на 50% получается полпикселя. Другое решение - сделать размеры четными.